# PHP Form data write

Tags: javascript, php, html

I manage the forums and site of this game server I play. There's an application forum and it writes the data to another file. It works perfectly fine,  I just have a question; I'm not all to good with PHP, as I'm more focused on learning JavaScript atm, but I would like to know if there would be a way that I could make it write into a grid/table format? Even better, an example with a short walk-through. Again, what I need is a way for it to write it in a "grid/table" format, IF possible. Here's the PHP document (with HTML), and the file that it would send it to.

## PHP / HTML:

```
<?php
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
    $errorMessage = "";

    if(empty($_POST['formSteam']))
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You need to put your Steam ID!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['formName']))
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>Please put your first and/or lastname!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['formAge']))
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>Please tell us your age! This is just for reference.</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['formApplication']))
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>Do I have to explain this? Please explain why you want to be apart of our staff!</li>";
    }
    $varSteam = $_POST['formSteam'];
    $varName = $_POST['formName'];
    $varAge = $_POST['formAge'];
    $varApplication = $_POST['formApplication'];

    if(empty($errorMessage)) 
    {
        $fs = fopen("mydata.csv","a");
        fwrite($fs,$varSteam . ", " . $varName . ", " . $varAge . ", " . $varApplication . "\n");
        fclose($fs);

        header("Location: success.html");
        exit;
    }
}
?> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Apply - POG</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <!-- This Template is a WiP - Please report any bugs to the administrative team at The Gaming Hideout. Thank you. All rights reserved. -->
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <h1><img src="VexIMG/header.png" alt="Possessed Gaming" width="760" height="60"></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
    <div class="navlinks">
    <div id="output2">
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="nav.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div id="altnav" style="min-height:200%;">
        <center><img src="VexIMG/Index/latest.png"></center>
        <p id="output1"></p>
        <script src="latest.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
    <?php
        if(!empty($errorMessage)) 
        {
            echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
            echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
        } 
    ?>
    <form action="application.php" method="post">
        <p>
            Whats your Steam ID? Find out <a href="http://www.steamidfinder.com">here!</a><br>
            <input type="text" name="formSteam" maxlength="50" value="<?=$varSteam;?>">
        </p>
        <p>
            What is your name?<br>
            <input type="text" name="formName" maxlength="50" value="<?=$varName;?>">
        </p>                
        <p>
                How old are you?<br>
                <input type="text" name="formAge" maxlength="2" value="<?=$varAge;?>">
        </p>
        <p>
            Why do you want to apply for PossessedGaming Staff?<br>
            <textarea name="formApplication" maxlength="3000" style="width:325px;height:150px;" value="<?=$varApplication;?>"></textarea>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    <div id="copyright">
    Copyright Â© The Gaming Hideout<br>
    We own no rights on any game on this site unless otherwise noted.<br>
    All Rights Reserved.
    </div>
    <div id="footnav">
    <script src="footnav.js"></script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

## FILE DATA / OUTCOME:

```
Steam ID, Name, Age, Reason     <!Pre-Made
----------------------------                 !>
(Le Applications Private)
STEAM_0:xxxx, Bob, 15, Because I'm just an example and I really want to be admin!
```

Comment: Currently, your output file is in csv , so for grid/table,  you have to change from csv to other. I wud suggest html.

Comment: This is what he want in php :)

Comment: @AmmarHayderKhan Would I be able to output it like that?

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is not the most elegant way to do this, but now it will do the job.

I am assuming, all the lines are valid, and has the 4 properties for all players.

Anyway, even if it not the most elegant, I hope you will get the point of it, so you can rewrite as you want.

```
<table>
    <?php
    $string = "Steam ID, Name, Age, Reason
(Le Applications Private)
STEAM_0:xxxx, Bob, 15, Because I'm just an example and I really want to be admin!
STEAM_1:xxxx, John, 18, This is my reason!
";

    $content = str_replace("\r","", explode("\n", $string));

//We need this, because we are need to use the first two row in special ways.
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($content as $row) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <?php
            if ($i == 1) {
                //This is the first row, so these are table headers.
                //Explode the row by commas into an array.
                $pieces = explode(',', $row);

                //Then show the value of arrays.
                ?>
                <th><?php echo $pieces[0]; ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $pieces[1]; ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $pieces[2]; ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $pieces[3]; ?></th>
                <?php
            } elseif ($i == 2) {
                //This is the second row, so we need to colspan it
                //Just echoing it, becuause in this row we do not need to
                //explode anythin.
                ?>
                <td colspan="4"><?php echo $row; ?></td>
                <?php
            } else {
                //All the players.

                //Do the same as the first row.
                $pieces = explode(',', $row);
                ?>
                <td><?php echo $pieces[0]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $pieces[1]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $pieces[2]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $pieces[3]; ?></td>
                <?php
            }
            $i++;
            ?>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```